# Are exposed database names on shared server a security hole?

Tags: databases, data-leakage

I was working for a client this week, and they use PostgreSQL database for web applications. They have their database on a shared server. When I connected to the database host with pgAdmin, I was surprised to see a list of all the databases and users on such server. Besides that, it's easy to extrapolate the website address from the names I have.

Is this a sign of a bigger issue, security flaws, or is it not really a big issue?

Comment: Are you referring to a shared server by a hosting service? There's basically no security there so don't worry about details like this.